# Can you use a style tag within a style tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Hey I'm using Styled Components for css handling in a design system library.
I'm having trouble with consuming apps not being able to override our component's css without using `!important`.

The problem stems from my styled-components injecting it's stylesheet tag at the end of the head.
By moving their style tags back I was able to let consuming apps easily override my styles.

This is my workaround for this -

```
let targetStylesheet: HTMLStyleElement;
function createLowPriorityStylesheet() {
  const stylesheet = document.createElement('style');
  stylesheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].prepend(stylesheet);

  return stylesheet;
}

...

if (!targetStylesheet && !isTest()) {
    targetStylesheet = createLowPriorityStylesheet();
}

return (
    <StyleSheetManager target={targetStylesheet}>
      <MyComponent />
    </StyleSheetManager>
  );
```

I'm creating an `<svg>` tag and **pre**pending it to the head, and styled components will inject `<style>` tags as children of the svg tag I created.

This solution seems to work fine but I couldn't find information saying it's a valid approach or anyone talking about why you shouldn't do this.

Are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: Cant you just make sure your style sheets are loaded last?

Comment: @Grumpy The only way I found to control where my styled components are appended is with `StyleSheetManager`'s target prop. But since it append and doesn't prepend, I can't let it write to the head tag since that will make my styles take higher prioritization. By prepending the svg in the head and letting styled write it's styles into it I'm keeping my styles less prioritized.